# Grails querying the database against a list of objects

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I'm creating an application with Grails.

I have two domain classes:

parent and child:

```
class Parent {
    string name


    hasMany[children: child]
}

class Child {
    string name

    belongsTo[parent: parent]
}
```

I search for all the parents with a name similar to a keyword:

```
def parents = Parent.findAll("From Parent as parent where parent.name like '%fra%'")
```

I'd like to query the database searching for all children that have a parent in the parents list.

How I could I accomplish that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does:

```
Child.findAllByParentInList( parents )
```

do it?

Comment: yes, it does. Thank you! I totally missed the InList comparator! thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using HQL you can achieve the same in a single query:

```
def children = Child.executeQuery("select c from Child as c \
                                  where c.parent.name like '%fra%'")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities, see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying

You could also query the children via:

```
    def children = Child.where {
        parent.name ==~ "%fra%"
    }.findAll()
```